# (Android) Maps (v2) not wroking after publishing signed APK with keystore, to Play Store

Tags: android, maps

I export my APK by signing a certificate (keystore) with it.
After Publishing my maps are not working, but working good while installing from Eclipse.
Maps not working when I download this app to use.

Comment: did you added hash key?

Comment: Yeah I used an API key generated from Google API console for Maps V2!

Comment: I found solution, Thanks for being supportive Shrikant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution, I resolved this issue.
I created Maps API Key by using SHA-1 of debug.keystore, as for testing app we usually do. I created a new API key by using SHA-1 for my Signed Keystore using keytool command, I used the API Key it and re-published/update my app.

More Help regarding this release key is Here:
[Display your app's certificate information](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this.  Kindly find the below steps to solve this.

Hope you have created API Key in Cloud Console with your android's default Keystore. (debug.keystore). So it will not be available after you published the app.

So you have to use common API key (Browser Key) or Create new API Key with your Signed APK Keystore file.

Select Create new Browser Key instead of Create Android Key in Cloud Console.

Upgrade the version code while re-applying this app.

Comment: Kindly give up for this answer. because it may  useful for others.

Comment: I resolved this issue. Similar to your solution, I created Maps API Key by using SHA-1 of debug.keystore as for testing app we usually do, previously so the Error.
Now, I created a new API key by using SHA-1 as in my Signed Keystore, I used it and re-published my app. The app is working fine now. Happy :)
Thanks alot for your support Sivakumar!

Comment: Sorry to not to give up, I'm building reputation to 15 to do it!